# Creation of Dynamic elements through XSLT

Tags: xslt

```xml
<mL>
  <s>1</s>
  <dt>2022-01-01-01.00.00</dt>
  <q>10</q>
</mL>
<mL>
  <s>2</s>
  <dt>2022-01-01-02.00.00</dt>
  <q>11</q>
</mL>
<mL>
  <s>3</s>
  <dt>2022-01-02-01.00.00</dt>
  <q>12</q>
</mL>
<mL>
  <s>4</s>
  <dt>2022-01-02-02.00.00</dt>
  <q>13</q>
</mL>
```

and I have to transform this structure into something like this based on the changing dates and the time intervals for e.g. in first 2 set of `ml` tags we can observe `<s>1</s>` and `<s>2</s>` have `<dt>2022-01-02-01.00.00</dt>` and `<dt>2022-01-02-02.00.00</dt>` here "2022-01-02" is date and "01.00.00" & "02.00.00" are time intervals, and we have to create the no of elements based on these intervals, only check the sample down here.

```xml
<Interval>
  <IntervalEnding_01.00.00>10</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
  <IntervalEnding_02.00.00>11</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
</Interval>
<Interval>
  <IntervalEnding_01.00.00>12</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
  <IntervalEnding_02.00.00>13</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
</Interval>
```

I tried using a template

```
     <xsl:template name="SplitInterval">
              <!--xsl:element name="Report_Period_date"-->
              <xsl:for-each select="ns1:idGrp/ns1:mL">
                    <xsl:element name="{concat('IntervalEnding','_', substring (ns1:dt, 1, 4 ),substring (ns1:dt, 6, 2 ),substring (ns1:dt, 9, 2 ),'_',substring (ns1:dt, 12, 2 ),substring (ns1:dt, 15, 2 ))}">
                          <xsl:value-of select="ns1:q"/>
                    </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <!--/xsl:element-->
        </xsl:template>
```

but I am only able to print like without the root Interval tag

```xml
<IntervalEnding_01.00.00>12</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
<IntervalEnding_02.00.00>13</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
```

But I need to print like below

```xml
<Interval>
  <IntervalEnding_01.00.00>12</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
  <IntervalEnding_02.00.00>13</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
</Interval>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) you are trying to do something like:

**XML (well-formed!!)**

```
<root>
    <mL>
        <s>1</s>
        <dt>2022-01-01-01.00.00</dt>
        <q>10</q>
    </mL>
    <mL>
        <s>2</s>
        <dt>2022-01-01-02.00.00</dt>
        <q>11</q>
    </mL>
    <mL>
        <s>3</s>
        <dt>2022-01-02-01.00.00</dt>
        <q>12</q>
    </mL>
    <mL>
        <s>4</s>
        <dt>2022-01-02-02.00.00</dt>
        <q>13</q>
    </mL>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="mL[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <Interval>
                <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::mL[1]">
                    <xsl:element name="IntervalEnding_{substring(dt, 12)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="q"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Interval>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Interval>
      <IntervalEnding_01.00.00>10</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
      <IntervalEnding_02.00.00>11</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
   </Interval>
   <Interval>
      <IntervalEnding_01.00.00>12</IntervalEnding_01.00.00>
      <IntervalEnding_02.00.00>13</IntervalEnding_02.00.00>
   </Interval>
</output>
```

Comment: This solution is grouping 2 elements per Interval tags, but I need all elements belonging to same date in a Single <Interval> tag

Comment: Then you need to perform grouping - see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info